# Dynamic pre-request script Postman

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I have this pre-request script and using runner to send bulk requests each second

```
     const moment = require('moment');
     postman.setEnvironmentVariable("requestid", moment().format("0223YYYYMMDDHHmmss000000"));
```

I need the “requestid” to be unique every time.

first request: "022320221115102036000001"

second request: "022320221115102037000002"

third request: "022320221115102038000003"
.
.
.

and so on until let’s say 1000 requests.

Basically, I need to make the last 6 digits dynamic.

Comment: I was writing an example for this, a few questions. Is the prefix always the same? `022320221115102036` ? Does it need to be a sequential number or could it be just a 6 digit incremental number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer can be found on [this postman request I've created](https://www.postman.com/southlondon/workspace/stackoverflow/request/19391207-5b03ceba-33b5-43fe-8e95-b17bd61c3554) for you. There's many ways to achieve this, given the little information provided, I've defaulted to:

- Set a baseline prefix (before the last 6 numbers)
- Give a start number for the last 6 numbers
- If there IS NOT a previous variable stored initialized with the values above
- If there IS a previous variable stored just increment it by one.
- The variable `date` is your final result, `current` is just the increment

You can see here sequential requests:

[image]

And here is the code, but I would test this directly on the request I've provided above:

```js
// The initial 6 number to start with
// A number starting with 9xxxxxx will be easier for String/Number converstions
const BASELINE = '900000'
const PREFIX = '022320221115102036'

// The previous used value if any
let current = pm.collectionVariables.get('current')

// If there's a previous number increment that, otherwise use the baseline
if (isNaN(current)) {
    current = BASELINE 
} else {
    current = Number(current) + 1
}

const date = PREFIX + current

// Final number you want to use
pm.collectionVariables.set('current', current)
pm.collectionVariables.set('date', PREFIX + date)
console.log(current)
console.log(date)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. The only thing remaining is that the date part in the prefix is not fixed and should be the current date time. in fact, only the 0223 part is fixed.

Comment: That is yet another question :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I changed your code a little bit and it worked perfectly!